# Previously clicked items being removed by modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have a modal that allows me to remove an `.item`.

Once I click on an item, the modal will appear and I can either select "confirm" or "cancel". If I select cancel for multiple items, but then on one item select "confirm", every previous clicked item will be removed.

How can I prevent this?

I have tried setting the variable `item` to `null` within the modal open function, then resetting the variable directly after, but that did not work.

```js
$(function() {

  var modal = $('.modal');

  $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var text = item.text();
    modal.show();
    modal.find('.modal-header').text('Are you sure you want to remove "' + text + '"?');
    $(document).on('click', '.modal-save', function() {
      item.remove();
      modal.hide();
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.modal-close', function() {
    modal.hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.item-container {
  background: #eee;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="item">one</div>
  <div class="item">two</div>
  <div class="item">three</div>
  <div class="item">four</div>
</div>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn modal-close">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn modal-save">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializing with a null and setting it to null when the modal is closed does it.

```js
$(function() {

  var modal = $('.modal');
  var item = null;
  $(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
    item = $(this);
    var text = item.text();
    modal.show();
    modal.find('.modal-header').text('Are you sure you want to remove "' + text + '"?');
    $(document).on('click', '.modal-save', function() {
      item.remove();
      modal.hide();
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.modal-close', function() {
    item = null;
    modal.hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.item-container {
  background: #eee;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="item">one</div>
  <div class="item">two</div>
  <div class="item">three</div>
  <div class="item">four</div>
</div>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn modal-close">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn modal-save">Confirm</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```